# Flash CC canvas - Text alignment issue

Tags: html, flash, canvas

I am converting a flash animation to html5 canvas using Flash CC. everything goes well but have issues on text alignment. is there a way to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi @Anandh please add more information about the problem, start by making a real question, giving the details of the problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: I've experienced this problem too, use of `TextField` is not recommended. I usually rasterize static text or use HTML and `DOMElement` instead.